# NoReverseMatch when using Apphook without namespace

Tags: django-cms

I use Django CMS 3 and Django 1.6 and the default [django polls app](https://github.com/divio/django-polls) , and I am doing [this](https://github.com/divio/django-cms-tutorial) short tutorial.

My problem is that the PollsApp works fine when it's using namespace like this:

**djangocms_polls/cms_app.py:**

```
...
class PollsApp(CMSApp):
    name = _("Poll App")
    urls = ["polls.urls"]
    app_name = "polls"
...
```

**polls/templates/polls/index.html:**

```
...
{% for poll in latest_poll_list %}
    <li><a href="{% url 'polls:detail' poll.id %}">{{ poll.question }}</a></li>
{% endfor %}
...
```

But when I delete the "polls:" part from the index.html, it won't work (and it doesn't matter if there is or isn't app_name field in PollsApp) and I get this Error:

> NoReverseMatch at /polls/
>
> Exception Value:
> Reverse for 'detail' with arguments '(1L,)' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 0 pattern(s) tried: []

Why am I making my life hard when everything works - you ask? It's because I want to use apps that doesn't use namespaces like django-shop and when I created apphook for django-shop - the same problem occured.

Comment: I think it's a bug in the tutorial. Check this out https://github.com/divio/django-cms-tutorial/issues/35

Answer (score 0):

When you're using apps via an Apphook in CMS you have to supply a namespace to when creating URLs in the templates.

In general also, when creating apps I believe it to be from a 'best practice' approach to always namespace your app and template URLs.

If you're using an app which doesn't make use of the `app_name` Meta attribute, you can define a namespace when you include an app's URLs in your root `urls.py`. Take a look over the example here; https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/http/urls/#reversing-namespaced-urls

Comment: But how could this be done if the [docs](http://docs.django-cms.org/en/latest/introduction/05-apphooks.html) of djangocms 3.5.x tell you should remove the application from the urls.py? The apphook defines a get_urls method, where `["apphookapp.urls"]` will be returned. So no ability to inject a namespace here

Comment: @woodz The `app_name` attr is the namespace; http://docs.django-cms.org/en/latest/introduction/05-apphooks.html#create-the-apphook-class

Comment: markwalker_: sure, but how will this help, if the application being hooked in doesn't make use of namespaced urls? You can define any neat name 
 for the `app_name` attr in your Apphook class. It still will rise the NoReverseMatch error since in the hooked application's templates **no** url can be resolved. There is simply no knowledge of a namespace in the hooked application.

Comment: @woodz I'm not sure it's valid to have an apphook without a namespace, because you lose control over the views and can't route traffic to your views. Specifically the CMS base view is `details`. When setting up pages in CMS for apphooks, you define an application instance name. You should also have a look at the docs for apphook configurations; http://docs.django-cms.org/en/latest/how_to/namespaced_apphooks.html#an-example-apphook-configuration

Comment: markwalker_: _When setting up pages in CMS for apphooks, you define an application instance name_. Yes and it gets automatically populated by the `app_name` attr of the Apphook class when hooked app is selected via the drop down _APPLICATION:_. So this `app_name` attr is anyhow required but it's totally diffuse how to deal with applications without namespacing. The doc has to make a clear explanation here. And if it is something like _applications without namespacing cannot be hooked in..._ it's a statement leastwise. The issue mentioned by @azuax is archived for 4 years now, but not solved.